# Yantra- Pran Pratishtha

Tags: vedas, mantras, tantra, yantra

My simple question is-

If, for some reason, yantra made from precious metals is not available for sadhana, is it possible to do pran-pratishtha on a paper(laminated) yantra and then use it for sadhana?

Comment: Yantras can be made from gold, silver or copper and copper is not precious.

Comment: @Rickross Kindly tell for paper.

Comment: Prana Pratishtha mantras and method are the same regardless of what the Yantra is made of. Question here is if it's allowed to draw it on ordinary paper or not. For some Yantras, Bhojpatra is recommended but not so sure about paper.